# If f is measurable then for any integer n $f^n$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

If $f$ is measurable , prove that $f^n$ is also a measurable function , where n is a positive integer.

**My understanding** Well if I check $f^1$ is measurable this is obvious since I was already given that f is measurable.

However, Do I have to prove that $f^2$ is measurable and $f^3$ is measurable and so on and then conclude than $f^n$ is measurable. And if so how do I know that for every n that the function $f$ is measurable.What if $f^(100)$ is not measurable per say. Under what circumstances can I conclude that for every n that this is true? I am using the H.L Royden and Walter Rudin but nothing else comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- In general if $u:X\to Y$ and $v:Y\to Z$ are measurable function then composition $v\circ u:X\to Z$ is a measurable function.
- Function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x^n$ is continuous, hence measurable if domain and codomain are both equipped with the sigma algebra of Borel sets.

Comment: This looks very concise and nice. Can you elaborate a little more for me on the composition function and why that implies the second argument which you stated? Or if you can provide a link to a suitable reading source or book. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, must leave now. Btw the second hint is not a consequence of the first. You must apply the first for $v=g$ and $u=f$. Then the composition is $f^n$

Comment: How do you define measurable? For the usual definition requiring that the preimage of Borel sets is measurable, what you wrote is not necessarily true.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo $x\mapsto x^n$ is a continuous, hence Borel-measurable function. Preimages of Borel sets are Borel sets.

Comment: @drhab Yes, that's the point. You need continuity of $v$ rather than just measurability.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I don't think so. If $u:X\to\mathbb R$ and $v:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are both measurable wrt Borel $\sigma$-algebra then also $v\circ u$ is measurable wrt Borel $\sigma$-algebra. No need of continuity.

Comment: Concerning compositions: If we work with measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal A)$, $(Y,\mathcal B)$ and $(Z,\mathcal C)$ and $u:X\to Y$ and $v:Y\to Z$ are measurable functions then for $C\in\mathcal C$ we find: $v^{-1}(C)\in\mathcal B$ and consequently $u^{-1}(v^{-1}(C))\in\mathcal A$. Now observe that $u^{-1}(v^{-1}(C))=(v\circ u)^{-1}(C)$ so this states that $v\circ u$ is measurable.

Comment: @drhab It seems there is a confusion although we are actually agreeing. The standard definition of measurability simply requires that preimages of Borel sets are measurable. For this notion it is not true that composition of measurable functions is measurable. If $v$ is not just measurable but continuous (and of course any assumption ensuring that the preimage by $v$ of Borel sets is Borel suffices) then $v\circ u$ is measurable if $u$ is measurable (without having to assume that $u^{-1}$ maps Borel sets to Borel sets). Again, as written, your answer (unintentionally) suggests something false.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you. I made an adaption. Things okay now?

Comment: @drhab I think that the person asking the problem should have at least specified  the definitions they are using, to avoid us having to sort them out.